# Configure isort to be compatible with flake8-import-order

Tags: flake8, isort

The pre-commit of our project is using flake8-import-order to ckeck import order validity.
I use to re-order imports using isort which produce an incompatible result specifically concerning the imports of the same sections.

isort doesn't insert a blank line between each different packages in the same section whereas flake8-import-order (I202) expect one

Did someone succeed to configure isort to make it compatible with flake8-import-order ?

`my_pkg_1` and `my_pkg_2` are both "first party" for isort, but I want this result :

```py
# known_first_party=my_pkg_1,my_pkg2

from my_pkg_1 import XXX
from my_pkg_1.AAA import YYY

from my_pkg2 import ZZZ
```

I know I can create custom sections using `known_XXX` but this django project have a lot of local packages.

Comment: if you're using an import sorter there's no reason to use `flake8-import-order`

Comment: I'm not responsible of pre-commit rules which use flake8-import-order in this project. I use isort inside my code editor.

Comment: I'd replace `flake8-import-order` with an import sorter personally, you'll probably be way less frustrated with a formatter than dealing with a linter